# function nil.id/0 is undefined or private - Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to test if a user id is equal to the resource id using guardian auth. If there is no current token and I try to go to a url that is checking for a token I get this error `function nil.id/0 is undefined or private`. I come from a ruby background and I don't know why it's saying `.id` is a function? and why this is throwing an error. Here is my code:

```
def index(conn, %{"user_id" => user_id}) do
    user = Repo.get(User, user_id)
           |> Repo.preload(:projects)
    cond do
      user.id == Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn).id ->
        conn
        |> render("index.html", projects: user.projects, user: user)
      :error ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "No access")
        |> redirect(to: session_path(conn, :new))
    end
  end
```

If there is no current_resource then it prints this error. But if there is no current_resource I just want it to continue to the :error path and render the session path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're calling `Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn).id` and `Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)` is `nil`. Since `nil` is an Atom in Elixir and so are modules, `.id` on it tries to call the function `id` on the module named `nil` (which doesn't exist). To fix this, you can add another check to see if `Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)` is not nil:

```
cond do
  (resource = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)) && user.id == resource.id ->
    conn
    |> render("index.html", projects: user.projects, user: user)
  :error ->
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "No access")
    |> redirect(to: session_path(conn, :new))
end
```

Comment: I appreciate the help I think you are right, but I'm get this error when I change to your code. `web/controllers/admin/project_controller.ex:12: undefined function resource/0`. That's when I change the line to this `resource == Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn) && user.id = resource.id`

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: That's `resource =`, not `==`.

Comment: Yeah. I also had to set it above the cond do. or else I would get this error `web/controllers/admin/project_controller.ex:12: undefined function resource/0`. Thanks for the help

Comment: resource = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
    cond do
      user.id == resource.id ->

Comment: In that case you should do `resource && user.id == resource.id ->`.

Comment: Yea, for some reason it's still giving me that error? weird

Comment: `** (CompileError) web/controllers/admin/project_controller.ex:12: undefined function resource/0`

Comment: I just updated my answer to put the assignment in parenthesis. Could you give that a try and see if it works?