# web/controllers/admin/project_controller.ex:12: undefined function resource/0 - elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to check the user_id against the resource id in my elixir function but I'm new to the language and I don't know why I'm getting this error `web/controllers/admin/project_controller.ex:12: undefined function resource/0`

Here is my code:

```
def index(conn, %{"user_id" => user_id}) do
    user = Repo.get(User, user_id)
           |> Repo.preload(:projects)
    cond do
      resource = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn) && user.id == resource.id ->
        conn
        |> render("index.html", projects: user.projects, user: user)
      :error ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "No access")
        |> redirect(to: session_path(conn, :new))
    end
  end
```

Am I actually setting the resource to the value of `Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)` or is that not how Elixir works. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Where are you getting `resource.id` from in this line `resource = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn) && user.id == resource.id ->`? Also, in this line of a `cond` control structure you can't bind/pattern match here. You can only check conditions where expressions are true/false.

Comment: Putting the assignment in parenthesis should fix this. I've updated my original answer from which the code in the question is from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41432647/320615.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @KeithA stated in his comment, you can't match values in your `cond` block so the reason you are getting `resource/0` undefined is because `resource = ...` doesn't work.

So therefore to make your code work you could do the following:

```
def index(conn, %{"user_id" => user_id}) do
    user = Repo.get(User, user_id)
           |> Repo.preload(:projects)
    resource = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)

    cond do
      user.id == resource.id ->
        conn
        |> render("index.html", projects: user.projects, user: user)
      :error ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "No access")
        |> redirect(to: session_path(conn, :new))
    end
  end
```